# Main.java:6: error: illegal start of expression public class TestClass{ ^ 1 error　と出てしまいます

Tags: java

paizaでこのようなコードを書いたのですが、`Main.java:6: error: illegal start of expression public class TestClass{ ^ 1 error`　と出てしまいます。どなたか解説お願いします。

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Your code here!
 public class TestClass{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Const con = new Const();
        }
    }

    class Const{
        Const(){
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        Const(int a){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        void hoge() {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`illegal start of expression public class TestClass`、つまり日本語にすると「`public class TestClass` の開始位置がおかしい」と言われています。

ソースコードを見ると、`main` 関数の定義の中で `TestClass` クラスの定義が始まってしまっています。Java でこのようなことはできません。